# saving the output on text file in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to print the results of huge matrix calculation but when I print it in text file using this method

```
rig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = file('Trimer.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f
for i,u in enumerate(Trimer_basis):
    print  u,':',i+1, 'times'
w, v = linalg.eig(EigenMatrix)
print "The energies are"
print w
```

it does not print the full results instead I got part of it as the following 
The energies are

```
[-6. -4. -2. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
```

I was wondering if there is better way to print such big data in text file ?

Comment: I think you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Print should ONLY be used for displaying to the console, you are looking for the write method of files.

```
with open('Trimer.txt', 'w') as f:

    for i,u in enumerate(Trimer_basis):
        w, v = linalg.eig(EigenMatrix)

    f.write(str(u) + " : " + str(i+1) + " times" + '\n')
    f.write(w)
```

The with block automatically closes the file when it exits